# Is InternetOpenUrl function on Windows secure enough? If not, how to make it stronger?

Tags: c, winapi, wininet

The [`InternetOpenUrl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098.aspx) documentation says:

> WinINet functions use a simple check against certificates by comparing for matching host names and simple wildcarding rules.

That suggests that it's not doing very much, and it can be circumvented by e.g. forging a self-signed certificate.

On the other hand, [KB 182888 "How To Handle Invalid Certificate Authority Error with WinInet"](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182888) suggests that WinInet functions are indeed checking with the root CA.

What is the truth? I would like [`InternetOpenUrl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098.aspx) to fail if cert is not valid. Or if it does not fail, then verify the cert ourselves, in the simplest possible way. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl; dr; Yes, InternetOpenUrl() checks for certificate authority by default.

I did a little test:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HINTERNET internet = InternetOpenA("Test Agent",
                                      INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL,
                                      0);
    assert(internet != NULL);
    char url[] = "https://urlgoeshere";
    HINTERNET connection = InternetOpenUrlA(internet,
                                           url,
                                           NULL,
                                           0,
                                           0,
                                           NULL);
    std::cout << "error while opening url " << url << " : "
              << GetLastError()
              << " handle: " << connection << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

And yes, when using a self-signed certificate it returns error code 12045, which is ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_CA.